# SFMC Audience Builder Audience into Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio, audience

We have just implemented SFMC Audience Builder and I want an audience to be injected into journey builder after it is published. What is the best way to do this?  I thought I could use automation studio to run the publish activist and then choose this audience as an entry source with the automation as the schedule, but it's not letting me do that.

Comment: Automation Studio's not allowing your to use the Publish Audience activity or you're unable to select the Data Extension published to as an entry for your Journey Builder Interaction?

Comment: I am successfully publishing the audience with Automation studio, and able to choose the Data Extension with tier a DE entry or Audience Entry source, however, I am not able to select "automation" when setting the schedule in journey builder to that the act of the automation completing is the journey's entry time.

Comment: As a workaround, I've set a recurring schedule but I still don't understand why I can't choose "automation" as the entry schedule as if this DE is not part of an automation.  It is true the automation only publishes the audience; there is no query on the DE.  Which, I suppose could be another work around, to build another DE and query the contents of the audience into a new DE to use for entry.

Comment: Aaah. I see. Yes. A workaround could be either a query that appends - "SELECT [myrequiredfields] WHERE 1=2" or create a filtered DE based on your audience with a filter that selects all records and then run a filter activity to refresh the filtered DE and use that filtered DE as your entry for the Journey Builder Interaction.